# Does WPF really internally use a WebBrowser control for the Frame control

Tags: .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987014/975018), the author proclaims:

> Since WPF uses the WebBrowser control under the hood, this should work
>   for the Frame control as well.

However, this doesn't make a lot of sense to me if the `Frame` is hosting a WPF page (obviously it's using a `WebBrowser` for web content). Does the `Frame` attempt to emulate a `WebBrowser` when it's hosting a `Page`, or does it actually somehow turn the `Page` into HTML, etc, then host it in a `WebBrowser`?

Answer (score 0):

Frame only uses WebBrowser to render HTML content, it renders WPF controls natively.

"When the Frame control navigates to HTML content, the Frame control internally instantiates the native WebBrowser ActiveX control."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx