# Turn off navigation page sound in WPF Frame control

Tags: wpf, navigation, audio, frame

I have a Frame element in a WPF window and all content in my application is loaded by using Frame.Navigate(). However, when navigating to a new page, there is that sound that is played by default, it's the same sound that is played in Internet Explorer. Is there any way I can turn of this sound from the application? I don't want to turn off setting in the control panel on OS level.
Thank you.

Edit: I guess the only way is to alter the sound on OS level, which can be done in the registry. This is acceptable solution for me.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vbgeneral/thread/843677F4-8F0B-46CB-986C-92E8042D0707

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there are no other ways, just to turn off in Windows settings like described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130204131644/http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2007/10/11/why-won-t-navigationservice-navigate-shut-up.aspx)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vbgeneral/thread/843677F4-8F0B-46CB-986C-92E8042D0707

Answer (score 1):

Dennis pointed out a solution here
[How to disable click sound in WebBrowser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393166/how-to-disable-click-sound-in-webbrowser-control) but in my case didn't work. So I modified the code as below and now all work fine:

**Usage**

```
URLSecurityZoneAPI.InternetSetFeatureEnabled(URLSecurityZoneAPI.InternetFeaturelist.DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, URLSecurityZoneAPI.SetFeatureOn.PROCESS, false);
```

**URLSecurityZoneAPI.vb**

```
''' Enables or disables a specified Internet Explorer feature control
''' Minimum availability: Internet Explorer 6.0
''' Minimum operating systems: Windows XP SP2
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security
Imports System

Friend Class URLSecurityZoneAPI

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specifies where to set the feature control value
    ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537168%28VS.85%29.aspx
    ''' </summary>
    Public Enum SetFeatureOn As Integer
        THREAD = &H1
        PROCESS = &H2
        REGISTRY = &H4
        THREAD_LOCALMACHINE = &H8
        THREAD_INTRANET = &H10
        THREAD_TRUSTED = &H20
        THREAD_INTERNET = &H40
        THREAD_RESTRICTED = &H80
    End Enum

    ''' <summary>
    ''' InternetFeaturelist
    ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537169%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
    ''' </summary>
    Public Enum InternetFeaturelist As Integer
        OBJECT_CACHING = 0
        ZONE_ELEVATION = 1
        MIME_HANDLING = 2
        MIME_SNIFFING = 3
        WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS = 4
        WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT = 5
        BEHAVIORS = 6
        DISABLE_MK_PROTOCOL = 7
        LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN = 8
        SECURITYBAND = 9
        RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL = 10
        VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL = 11
        RESTRICT_FILEDOWNLOAD = 12
        ADDON_MANAGEMENT = 13
        PROTOCOL_LOCKDOWN = 14
        HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE = 15
        SAFE_BINDTOOBJECT = 16
        UNC_SAVEDFILECHECK = 17
        GET_URL_DOM_FILEPATH_UNENCODED = 18
        TABBED_BROWSING = 19
        SSLUX = 20
        DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS = 21
        DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION = 22
        FORCE_ADDR_AND_STATUS = 23
        XMLHTTP = 24
        DISABLE_TELNET_PROTOCOL = 25
        FEEDS = 26
        BLOCK_INPUT_PROMPTS = 27
        MAX = 28
    End Enum


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Set the internet feature enabled/disabled
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="feature">The feature from <c>InternetFeaturelist</c></param>
    ''' <param name="target">The target from <c>SetFeatureOn</c></param>
    ''' <param name="enabled">enabled the feature?</param>
    ''' <returns><c>true</c> if [is internet set feature enabled] [the specified feature]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    Public Shared Function InternetSetFeatureEnabled(feature As InternetFeaturelist, target As SetFeatureOn, enabled As Boolean) As Boolean
        Return (SafeNativeMethods.CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(CInt(feature), CInt(target), enabled) = 0)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the internet feature is enabled.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="feature">The feature from <c>InternetFeaturelist</c></param>
    ''' <param name="target">The target from <c>SetFeatureOn</c></param>
    ''' <returns><c>true</c> if the internet feature is enabled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    ''' </returns>
    Public Shared Function IsInternetSetFeatureEnabled(feature As InternetFeaturelist, target As SetFeatureOn) As Boolean
        Return (SafeNativeMethods.CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled(CInt(feature), CInt(target)) = 0)
    End Function

End Class

<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()>
Friend NotInheritable Class SafeNativeMethods

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Enables or disables a specified feature control. 
    ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537168%28VS.85%29.aspx
    ''' </summary>            
    <SecurityCritical, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport("urlmon.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Friend Shared Function CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(featureEntry As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> dwFlags As Integer, fEnable As Boolean) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.[Error])> Integer
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified feature control is enabled. 
    ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537164%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
    ''' </summary>
    <SecurityCritical, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport("urlmon.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Friend Shared Function CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled(featureEntry As Integer, dwFlags As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.[Error])> Integer
    End Function

End Class
```

Note the adding of class named `SafeNativeMethods`