# CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled in Delphi2010

Tags: windows, delphi, browser, c++

I am trying to deactivate the annoying sound when clicking a link in WebBrowser control, WITHOUT changing the user registry. I've found documentation that this can be done through [CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649488.aspx), also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393166/how-to-disable-click-sound-in-webbrowser-control). But i have no idea how to implement it on Delphi 2010, since i am getting "Undeclared Identifier" error after including URLMon unit into the project and not much documentation out there.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might get some tips from this page. http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid9C9871FBCA710621B778496CC84F0FB4B5D48218.aspx?s=cryptoapi

Comment: Yes im trying to get some light from that code, but not much luck so far... thats from the embededWB (which i dont wanna use in my app), but i still cant make that CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled work in delphi

Answer (score 5):

`CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled()` and `CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled()` are not included in D2010's copy of UrlMon.pas.  You will have to declare them manually, eg:

```
const
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_THREAD = $00000001;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_PROCESS = $00000002;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_REGISTRY = $00000004;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_THREAD_LOCALMACHINE = $00000008;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_THREAD_INTRANET = $00000010;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_THREAD_TRUSTED = $00000020;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_THREAD_INTERNET = $00000040;
  GET_FEATURE_FROM_THREAD_RESTRICTED = $00000080;

  SET_FEATURE_ON_THREAD = $00000001;
  SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS = $00000002;
  SET_FEATURE_IN_REGISTRY = $00000004;
  SET_FEATURE_ON_THREAD_LOCALMACHINE = $00000008;
  SET_FEATURE_ON_THREAD_INTRANET = $00000010;
  SET_FEATURE_ON_THREAD_TRUSTED = $00000020;
  SET_FEATURE_ON_THREAD_INTERNET = $00000040;
  SET_FEATURE_ON_THREAD_RESTRICTED = $00000080; 

type
  INTERNETFEATURELIST = (
    FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING,
    FEATURE_ZONE_ELEVATION,
    FEATURE_MIME_HANDLING,
    FEATURE_MIME_SNIFFING,
    FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS,
    FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT,
    FEATURE_BEHAVIORS,
    FEATURE_DISABLE_MK_PROTOCOL,
    FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN,
    FEATURE_SECURITYBAND,
    FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL,
    FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL,
    FEATURE_RESTRICT_FILEDOWNLOAD,
    FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT,
    FEATURE_PROTOCOL_LOCKDOWN,
    FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE,
    FEATURE_SAFE_BINDTOOBJECT,
    FEATURE_UNC_SAVEDFILECHECK,
    FEATURE_GET_URL_DOM_FILEPATH_UNENCODED,
    FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING,
    FEATURE_SSLUX,
    FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS,
    FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION,
    FEATURE_FORCE_ADDR_AND_STATUS,
    FEATURE_XMLHTTP,
    FEATURE_DISABLE_TELNET_PROTOCOL,
    FEATURE_FEEDS,
    FEATURE_BLOCK_INPUT_PROMPTS,
    FEATURE_ENTRY_COUNT
  );

function CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled(FeatureEntry: INTERNETFEATURELIST; dwFlags: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'urlmon.dll'
function CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FeatureEntry: INTERNETFEATURELIST; dwFlags: DWORD; fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'urlmon.dll'

begin
  if CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, GET_FEATURE_FROM_PROCESS) = S_FALSE then
    CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, True); 
end;
```

Comment: For reference, I believe this works if the logic is altered: The snippet is testing if the feature is enabled, and if so, enable it.  It should be testing to see if the feature is not enabled, then enable it.  (For this scenario, instead of testing against S_OK, test against S_FALSE)

Comment: @RemyLebeau In XE4 and XE5 UrlMon is missing many interfaces. I wonder why isn't it being updated even though its from Embarcadero? For example `IInternetBindInfoEx,IInternetProtocolEx,IUri` just to name a few.

Comment: You will have to ask Embarcadero about that, and file a QC ticket to mention the missing interfaces.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll post a question. It seems they rely on JEDI to convert the headers for them.