# Delphi XE2 winapi.urlmon.CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled not found?

Tags: delphi, winapi, audio, twebbrowser, urlmon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled in Delphi2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702285/cointernetisfeatureenabled-in-delphi2010)

I am trying to disable the annoying click on navigate sound in twebbrowser control but i can't seem to see the winapi.urlmon. CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled anywhere?

Comment: It's not there. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4704342/243614) has declarations of both `CoInternetIsFeatureEnabled` and `CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled`.