# Remove the "click" sound from Winform WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, webbrowser-control, click

Does anyone know how to remove the "click" sound you get when navigating to another page, when using a WebBrowser on a WinForm? I would have thought they would have included an option to choose whether you want it enabled, but they didn't.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456/howto-disable-webbrowser-click-sound-in-your-app-only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393166/how-to-disable-click-sound-in-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but here's the solution I used:

I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393166/how-to-disable-click-sound-in-webbrowser-control) which Jørn Schou-Rode suggested in the comment.
It worked perfectly for me and didn't require any messing around in the control panel, which is great if you want it to be the same for each user that uses the program.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sound option that's only available from within the Windows Control Panel:

`Control Panel` > `Sounds and Audio Devices` > `Sounds` > `Start Navigation`

Set the sound to *(None)*

**EDIT**: I realized that you might be asking if there's a *programmatic* way of disabling the click sound; the answer would be **No**.  Like the other poster said, the WebBrowser control uses the IE engine, so therefore it uses IE's settings.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you'll find this is the IE browser's navigate sound, as set in Windows' sound options.  Because the control uses the IE browser engine it's possibly not something you can change programmatically without affecting the user's settings.

You could prove this simply enough by fiddling in control panel...