# Muting refresh sound in webbrowser control c# winform

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a webbrowser control on my form that runs in the background.  The page is constantly refreshing.  So I hear the refresh click everytime.  Is there a way to mute it?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [HowTo Disable WebBrowser 'Click Sound' in your app only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456/howto-disable-webbrowser-click-sound-in-your-app-only)

Comment: are sounds setting on your machine set to `no sound`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code snippet to solve this problem. It makes use of url monitor dll.

```
const int FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS = 21;

const int SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS = 0x00000002;

[DllImport("urlmon.dll")]
[PreserveSig]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
static extern int CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(
    int FeatureEntry,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFlags,
    bool fEnable);

static void DisableClickSounds()
{
    CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(
        FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS,
        SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS,
        true);
}
```